# How to modify this data structure in python

Tags: python

I have the following structure in Python.

```
{
  "TimeSeries": [{
    "Values": [
      [1428278400000.0, 44.44],
      [1428282000000.0, 46.15],
      [1428285600000.0, 38.46],
      [1428289200000.0, 47.62],
      [1428292800000.0, 35.29],
      [1428296400000.0, 40.0],
      [1428300000000.0, 33.33],
      [1428303600000.0, 43.48],
      [1428307200000.0, 44.44],
      [1428310800000.0, 40.0],
      [1428314400000.0, 47.22],
      [1428318000000.0, 37.93],
      [1428321600000.0, 45.45],
      [1428325200000.0, 46.15],
      [1428328800000.0, 42.86],
      [1428332400000.0, 44.83],
      [1428336000000.0, 47.37],
      [1428339600000.0, 40.0],
      [1428343200000.0, 38.46],
      [1428346800000.0, 47.06],
      [1428350400000.0, 42.31],
      [1428354000000.0, 50.0],
      [1428357600000.0, 47.62],
      [1428361200000.0, 42.86],
      [1428364800000.0, 0.0]
    ],
    "name": "Server2"
  }, {
    "Values": [
      [1428278400000.0, 55.56],
      [1428282000000.0, 53.85],
      [1428285600000.0, 61.54],
      [1428289200000.0, 52.38],
      [1428292800000.0, 64.71],
      [1428296400000.0, 60.0],
      [1428300000000.0, 66.67],
      [1428303600000.0, 56.52],
      [1428307200000.0, 55.56],
      [1428310800000.0, 60.0],
      [1428314400000.0, 52.78],
      [1428318000000.0, 62.07],
      [1428321600000.0, 54.55],
      [1428325200000.0, 53.85],
      [1428328800000.0, 57.14],
      [1428332400000.0, 55.17],
      [1428336000000.0, 52.63],
      [1428339600000.0, 60.0],
      [1428343200000.0, 61.54],
      [1428346800000.0, 52.94],
      [1428350400000.0, 57.69],
      [1428354000000.0, 50.0],
      [1428357600000.0, 52.38],
      [1428361200000.0, 57.14],
      [1428364800000.0, 0.0]
    ],
    "name": "Server1"
  }],
  "dates": [1428278400000.0, 1428282000000.0, 1428285600000.0, 1428289200000.0, 1428292800000.0, 1428296400000.0, 1428300000000.0, 1428303600000.0, 1428307200000.0, 1428310800000.0, 1428314400000.0, 1428318000000.0, 1428321600000.0, 1428325200000.0, 1428328800000.0, 1428332400000.0, 1428336000000.0, 1428339600000.0, 1428343200000.0, 1428346800000.0, 1428350400000.0, 1428354000000.0, 1428357600000.0, 1428361200000.0, 1428364800000.0]
}
```

Where `TimeSeries` is a list of dictionary of values consisting of epoch dates and values, and `dates` is a sorted epoch date list. Now I want to remove the last value from both `server2` and `server1` since its essentially zero and then remove the last corresponding date.

So the final structure becomes.

```
{
  "TimeSeries": [{
    "Values": [
      [1428278400000.0, 44.44],
      [1428282000000.0, 46.15],
      [1428285600000.0, 38.46],
      [1428289200000.0, 47.62],
      [1428292800000.0, 35.29],
      [1428296400000.0, 40.0],
      [1428300000000.0, 33.33],
      [1428303600000.0, 43.48],
      [1428307200000.0, 44.44],
      [1428310800000.0, 40.0],
      [1428314400000.0, 47.22],
      [1428318000000.0, 37.93],
      [1428321600000.0, 45.45],
      [1428325200000.0, 46.15],
      [1428328800000.0, 42.86],
      [1428332400000.0, 44.83],
      [1428336000000.0, 47.37],
      [1428339600000.0, 40.0],
      [1428343200000.0, 38.46],
      [1428346800000.0, 47.06],
      [1428350400000.0, 42.31],
      [1428354000000.0, 50.0],
      [1428357600000.0, 47.62],
      [1428361200000.0, 42.86]
    ],
    "name": "Server2"
  }, {
    "Values": [
      [1428278400000.0, 55.56],
      [1428282000000.0, 53.85],
      [1428285600000.0, 61.54],
      [1428289200000.0, 52.38],
      [1428292800000.0, 64.71],
      [1428296400000.0, 60.0],
      [1428300000000.0, 66.67],
      [1428303600000.0, 56.52],
      [1428307200000.0, 55.56],
      [1428310800000.0, 60.0],
      [1428314400000.0, 52.78],
      [1428318000000.0, 62.07],
      [1428321600000.0, 54.55],
      [1428325200000.0, 53.85],
      [1428328800000.0, 57.14],
      [1428332400000.0, 55.17],
      [1428336000000.0, 52.63],
      [1428339600000.0, 60.0],
      [1428343200000.0, 61.54],
      [1428346800000.0, 52.94],
      [1428350400000.0, 57.69],
      [1428354000000.0, 50.0],
      [1428357600000.0, 52.38],
      [1428361200000.0, 57.14]
    ],
    "name": "Server1"
  }],
  "dates": [1428278400000.0, 1428282000000.0, 1428285600000.0, 1428289200000.0, 1428292800000.0, 1428296400000.0, 1428300000000.0, 1428303600000.0, 1428307200000.0, 1428310800000.0, 1428314400000.0, 1428318000000.0, 1428321600000.0, 1428325200000.0, 1428328800000.0, 1428332400000.0, 1428336000000.0, 1428339600000.0, 1428343200000.0, 1428346800000.0, 1428350400000.0, 1428354000000.0, 1428357600000.0, 1428361200000.0]
}
```

How to achieve this in python.

Comment: Do you want to remove all the data which is  essentially zero or merely the last one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pop off the last item of the list:

```
for t in my_data['TimeSeries']:
    date, _ = t['Values'].pop()
my_data['dates'].remove(date)
```

This will update the original `my_data` in place. I've assumed the `date` is the same for the last item in the lists.

Answer (score 0):

to remove the last value from a list use

```
 _list = _list[0:len(_list)-1]
```

where _list can be burried in some other data structure...

```
 crazyData['yatta'][42]['foo']['here is my list'] = crazyData['yatta'][42]['yatta']['here is my list'][0:len(crazyData['yatta'][42]['yatta']['here is my list'])-1]
```

^ I know you like to use the scroll bar too.

Comment: This constructs a whole new list, which you would need to assign back into the structure, `pop()` does the same thing without constructing a new list.

Comment: Lol it is funny that python lists implement a pop without a push. I never even knew.